# Should I edit environment for VS Code when star running new program

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I still can't figure out how the VS code works. Should I have to edit the environment every time when I start running a (python) code?

Is VS Code a good choice for Python coder at all?

Comment: Have you installed the Python Extension? VS Code is a good choice for Python, but currently it (afaik) lacks a good interactive shell.

Comment: yes extension is installed properly. thanks for reply.

Comment: And you can't just execute the code via F5?

Comment: its executed but problem is, its always executed from desktop. that means:
no matter where my script file is, if I run the code:
os.getcwd()
it always shows its current directory is desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VScode is fine for writing and running python scripts. You can always run your script from the editor window by placing cursor in the editor window and right-clicking and selecting the option "Run Python File in Terminal". You should also install the Code Runner extension. This enables many ways to run or stop your script. You can read what the [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Code%20Runner&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) enables you to do to run your scripts.